# How could I receive files (on windows) from pendrive which were pasted there on linux?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

I have following issue: I had pendrive formatted for windows and copied there some files on linux (ubuntu), now on windows Vista I can't see them (folder seems to be empty). Is there any free software to get files back on windows?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unmount the drive on Linux to ensure that the files are written. You can do so by right-clicking on the drive and choosing the unmount or eject options, or by passing the `umount` command the path or device to unmount.

Comment: Unfortunetly, I don't have access to source computer now, is there any other solution?

Comment: No. If the file isn't there then the file isn't there.